# POSTing data while redirecting to a third-party URL using Response.Redirect()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

In ASP.Net Core 2.0, how can I POST data while redirecting to a third-party URL using `Response.Redirect()`?

Note: I have to POST this data without using the query-string.

Comment: I have to redirect the url with data to third party payment gateway. So how can I achieve this using Response.Redirect() method in ASP.Net Core 2.0? or else if you have anyother ideas please suggest me.

Comment: For example my third party pamentgateway url is:  http://xxxx:xxxx/PaymentGatewayWrapper.aspx

var requestData="some data";
Dictionary<string, object> postData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
postData.Add("requestToJson", requestData);

Finaly I have to redirect to above url with this postData

Answer (score 1):

Response.Redirect triggers a GET request which means that the only option is using a query string.
Can you trigger the redirection from the client (if any) in order to make a POST request?

Comment: I have to redirect the url with data to third party payment gateway.  So how can I achieve this using Response.Redirect() method in ASP.Net Core 2.0? or else if you have anyother ideas please suggest me.

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-http-post-web-request/4015346#4015346

Answer (score 0):

You must use object if you want post data without using query string.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Search([FromBody] CustomerSearchRequestApiModel request)
{       
    if (request == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();    
    }

    return Ok(request);
}
```

Comment: I have to redirect the url with data to third party payment gateway.  So how can I achieve this using Response.Redirect() method in ASP.Net Core 2.0? or else if you have anyother ideas please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to use `Response.Redirect()` to send `Post` request.

For a workaround, you could try `HttpClient` to send `Post` request and then return the reponse to the web browser with `ContentResult` as `text/html`.

Here is a demo code:

```
        public async Task<ContentResult> HtmlView()
    {
        using (var formDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            Article article = new Article { ArticleName = "AN" };

            formDataContent.Add(new StringContent("AN", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"), "ArticleName");
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(@"https://localhost:44393/Articles/Create", formDataContent);
                return new ContentResult
                {
                    ContentType = "text/html",
                    StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode,
                    Content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                };

            }
        }
    }
```

**Note**

Change the `HttpClient` part to send the right request to your own third party url with validate parameters.

Comment: Hi Tao Zho, thanks for your reply but the Requirement is:
POSTing data while redirecting to a third-party payment gateway URL using Response.Redirect()
then that third-party URL will be open a web page in that page user has to enter theire credentials for payment purpose.